# Can we use different storage engine in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, nosql

I MySql proving different types of storage engine like InnoDB etc. And every storage engine have different features then others.

I want know if we have such a type of mechanism in SQL Server also? If yes then how can we use these engines in SQL Server?

And it is possible that SQL Server will provide any NoSql types storage engine in future?

Comment: No, SQL Server doesn't have any replaceable "storage engine" now, and I don't seem to hear any rumors about Microsoft starting to provide such storage engines, either. And I don't believe the likelihood of a "NoSQL" storage engine for SQL Server is very high .....

Comment: Some time ago I also read some blog mention that PostgreSql have such type of features to support both Relation and Nosql database support , Its true ?